# Set white background with plot that includes marginals (ggExtra + ggplot2)

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to generate a PDF with many plots, one per page. These plots contain marginal distributions on the sides, generated with `ggExtra`:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggExtra)
set.seed(1)

pdf("example.pdf", width = 5, height=5, bg = "white")
for(i in 1:10){
  plot.df <- data.frame(x = rnorm(1000), y = rnorm(1000))

  p1 <- ggplot(plot.df, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
    geom_point() +
    ggtitle(i)
  p1 <- ggMarginal(p1)
  plot(p1)
}
dev.off()
```

However, the plots appear with a grey grid background instead of white background (see below). How can I make all the background white? Also, the output PDF contains a blank page at the beginning. How can avoid it being created?

[image: marginals with ggExtra]

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the [theme](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/ggtheme.html) of the plot. You can choose for example `theme_void()`, or make your own using `theme()`, and add it to your plot.

```
p1 <- ggplot(plot.df, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
    geom_point() +
    ggtitle(i) +
    theme_void()
```

---

Example of `theme_void()` :

[image]

Comment: This only changes the background for the plot generated with ggplot2. The problem is when using ggMarginal only (since it works with grids).

Comment: @drgxfs did you find a solution? I have the same issue and I can second that theme() only alters the original plot.

Comment: Yes, you can plot using grid.draw() instead of plot().